# Job Application

Tags: nodes, forms, webforms

I have a content type called "Job", that has fields for the job and an email field for the job contact. At the bottom of each job node  there should be a button "apply now". If you click on the button, there should be a form with textfields, file upload (for the resumee) etc. If you send your application, an email should be sent to the job contact email (which is inside the job node).

What is the best way to achieve this? First I was thinking about using webforms, but I don't know how to get the job contact email form the node as the sendto webform email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two content types

1. Job
2. Job Application

In `Job Application`, where you have resume upload etc, add a `entity reference` field to `Job` content type.

Then when you list the `Job` and add a link `Apply Now` to create `Job Application`.

Use [Entity Refernce Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) module to prepopulate the entity reference in `Job Applciation` based on URL.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9C4Uf6euLY) is good video tutorial expaining `Enity Reference Prepopualte` module.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the default webform behaviours. Create and save the webform. Then, within the node/%nid/edit page, go to Webform > Emails and fill in your email there. There's no need to have the email as a separate field on the node.

Comment: But the email is different for each node. The user should enter the email but the user should not need to enter his email within the webform (or ever have to create the webform manually).

Comment: ok, in that case, use @wolverine's solution.